# Properly authenticating users of Chrome Extension and Website

Tags: web-services, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension where the user authenticates himself with Google oAuth of type Chrome App. It then checks for in-app payment info and calls a webservice from my website. On my website, I use oAuth of type Web Application to have my users register with a Google email only.

Since, chrome extensions are javascripts that can be spoofed, I want to in some way ensure that when my web service is being called, it is indeed from the person who claims it is. Since, the oAuth is happening on two different client ids without the possibility of a merge, I want to ask if there can be any alternate ways to ensure that the person who is authenticated in the extension is indeed the person calling the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get an access token for a user in the Chrome extension, send it to your server (over HTTPS). Have the server make an API request to Google authenticated with that access token to get the user's email/id. You then know who that user is and you can generate an access token for your own site to return to the chrome extension for further use.

Comment: Problem is that the token generated by the extension is specially for Chrome Extensions/Apps and may not work with the website one.

Comment: An access token is used by itself to authenticate a user. Once it's created it doesn't need to be accompanied with application credentials.